# Positioning edge label

Tags: labels, edge

I'm trying to position two edge labels over and below their respective edges. I'd like them to be center aligned in relation to the edge. This is my current code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={rectangle,thick}]

\begin{scope}[x  = {(0.5cm,0.5cm)},
                      y  = {(0.95cm,-0.25cm)},
                        z  = {(0cm,0.9cm)}, 
                        canvas is yz plane at x=-1]
    \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](A) at (-.9, -.9) {};
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](B) at (-.6, -.7) {};
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](C) at (.7, -.2) {};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[x  = {(0.5cm,0.5cm)},
                      y  = {(0.95cm,-0.25cm)},
                        z  = {(0cm,0.9cm)}, 
                        canvas is xz plane at y=1]
    \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](D) at (-.5, -.55) {};
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](E) at (.7, -.1) {};
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](F) at (-.8, -.08) {};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[x  = {(0.5cm,0.5cm)},
                      y  = {(0.95cm,-0.25cm)},
                        z  = {(0cm,0.9cm)}, 
                        canvas is yx plane at z=1]
    \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](G) at (.7, .7) {};
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](H) at (-0.8, .4) {};
    \node[above] at (current bounding box.north) {$\mathbb{R}^n$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope} 
    \draw[step=0.3,gray,very thin] (2,-2.5) grid ++(3,3);

    \node[box,fill=green] at (2.55,-2.25){};
    \node[box,fill=green] at (2.25,-2.25){};    
    \node[box,fill=lime] at (4.05,-1.95){};
    \node[box,fill=lime] at (4.65,-1.95){};
    \node[box,fill=teal] at (4.65,-1.05){};
    \node[box,fill=lime] at (4.35,-1.65){};
    \node[box,fill=olive] at (4.65,0.15){};
    \node[box,fill=yellow] at (3.75,0.15){};

    \draw [<-,red](A.east)      to [out=-60,in=-130] (2.55,-2.15);
    \draw [->,blue](A.south)    to [out=-60,in=-130] (2.55,-2.25) node[sloped,below,font=\tiny] {Label};    
    \draw [<-,red](B.east)      to [out=-60,in=-150] (2.25,-2.15);
    \draw [->,blue](B.south)    to [out=-60,in=-150] (2.25,-2.25);
    \draw [<-,red](C.east)      to [out=-60,in=-180] (4.05,-1.90);
    \draw [->,blue](C.south)    to [out=-60,in=-180] (4.05,-2);
    \draw [<-,red](D.east)      to [out=0,in=-190]   (4.65,-1.90);
    \draw [->,blue](D.south)    to [out=0,in=-190]   (4.65,-2);
    \draw [<-,red](E.east)      to [out=-30,in=-180] (4.65,-0.99);
    \draw [->,blue](E.south)    to [out=-30,in=-180] (4.65,-1.09);
    \draw [<-,red](F.east)      to [out=0,in=-200] (4.35,-1.60);
    \draw [->,blue](F.south)    to [out=0,in=-200] (4.35,-1.70);
    \draw [<-,red](G.east)      to [out=10,in=-220] (4.65,0.2) node[sloped,above,font=\tiny] {$P^{-1}$};
    \draw [->,blue](G.south)    to [out=10,in=-220] (4.65,0.1);
    \draw [<-,red](H.east)      to [out=-5,in=180] (3.75,0.2);
    \draw [->,blue](H.south)    to [out=-5,in=180] (3.75,0.1);
\end{scope}

\coordinate(grid) at (2.9,0.5);
\node[above] at (grid.north) {$\mathbb{R}^2$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

I tried to used the `midway` keyword but the result was a misplaced (at least not what I was expecting) label:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this ?

[image]

Put the node before the  edge end not after

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={rectangle,thick}]

\begin{scope}[x  = {(0.5cm,0.5cm)},
                      y  = {(0.95cm,-0.25cm)},
                        z  = {(0cm,0.9cm)}, 
                        canvas is yz plane at x=-1]
    \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](A) at (-.9, -.9) {};
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](B) at (-.6, -.7) {};
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](C) at (.7, -.2) {};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[x  = {(0.5cm,0.5cm)},
                      y  = {(0.95cm,-0.25cm)},
                        z  = {(0cm,0.9cm)}, 
                        canvas is xz plane at y=1]
    \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](D) at (-.5, -.55) {};
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](E) at (.7, -.1) {};
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](F) at (-.8, -.08) {};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[x  = {(0.5cm,0.5cm)},
                      y  = {(0.95cm,-0.25cm)},
                        z  = {(0cm,0.9cm)}, 
                        canvas is yx plane at z=1]
    \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](G) at (.7, .7) {};
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=gray](H) at (-0.8, .4) {};
    \node[above] at (current bounding box.north) {$\mathbb{R}^n$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope} 
    \draw[step=0.3,gray,very thin] (2,-2.5) grid ++(3,3);

    \node[box,fill=green] at (2.55,-2.25){};
    \node[box,fill=green] at (2.25,-2.25){};    
    \node[box,fill=lime] at (4.05,-1.95){};
    \node[box,fill=lime] at (4.65,-1.95){};
    \node[box,fill=teal] at (4.65,-1.05){};
    \node[box,fill=lime] at (4.35,-1.65){};
    \node[box,fill=olive] at (4.65,0.15){};
    \node[box,fill=yellow] at (3.75,0.15){};

    \draw [<-,red](A.east)      to [out=-60,in=-130] (2.55,-2.15);
    \draw [->,blue](A.south)    to [out=-60,in=-130]node[sloped,below,font=\tiny] {Label} (2.55,-2.25) ; % modified
    \draw [<-,red](B.east)      to [out=-60,in=-150] (2.25,-2.15);
    \draw [->,blue](B.south)    to [out=-60,in=-150] (2.25,-2.25);
    \draw [<-,red](C.east)      to [out=-60,in=-180] (4.05,-1.90);
    \draw [->,blue](C.south)    to [out=-60,in=-180] (4.05,-2);
    \draw [<-,red](D.east)      to [out=0,in=-190]   (4.65,-1.90);
    \draw [->,blue](D.south)    to [out=0,in=-190]   (4.65,-2);
    \draw [<-,red](E.east)      to [out=-30,in=-180] (4.65,-0.99);
    \draw [->,blue](E.south)    to [out=-30,in=-180] (4.65,-1.09);
    \draw [<-,red](F.east)      to [out=0,in=-200] (4.35,-1.60);
    \draw [->,blue](F.south)    to [out=0,in=-200] (4.35,-1.70);
    \draw [<-,red](G.east)      to [out=10,in=-220] (4.65,0.2) node[sloped,above,font=\tiny] {$P^{-1}$};
    \draw [->,blue](G.south)    to [out=10,in=-220] (4.65,0.1);
    \draw [<-,red](H.east)      to [out=-5,in=180] (3.75,0.2);
    \draw [->,blue](H.south)    to [out=-5,in=180] (3.75,0.1);
\end{scope}

\coordinate(grid) at (2.9,0.5);
\node[above] at (grid.north) {$\mathbb{R}^2$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```